# is if-statement bad for OpenACC?

Tags: if-statement, openacc, pgi

I heard that OpenACC does not handle if-statement efficiently and should try to avoid using it.

For example, it is no good to do something like that (loop with a couple of if-statement) in the device/OpenACC:

```
for (m=0; m<polygon2.num_vertices; m++) {

    polygon2Vertex1 = listOfpolygon2Vertex[m];

    if ((m+1) == polygon2.num_vertices){
        // last vertex, so we get last and the first vertex
        polygon2Vertex2 = listOfpolygon2Vertex[0];

    } else {
        // not the last vertex, so we get [m] and [m+1] vertex
        polygon2Vertex2 = listOfpolygon2Vertex[m+1];
    }

    result = doIntersect(polygon1Vertex1, polygon1Vertex2, polygon2Vertex1, polygon2Vertex2);

    if (result==1){
        // found that these 2 edges intersect.
        // no need to further check

        break;
    }
}
```

is it true? If so, what can I do to handle if-statement in OpenACC?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with branch divergence within a CUDA warp.  Since all threads in a warp execute the same instruction at the same time, if some of the threads take one branch and the rest take another, you've doubled your time.  However, it's only a problem within a warp.  So if all the threads within the same warp take one branch, and all the threads in another warp take a different branch, then there will be no performance impact.

If you don't know what a warp is, this in old but still good article on the CUDA threading model: http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a5.htm

With this code, since only the last element takes the true case, the if statement will have very little impact.

I'd would recommend inverting your logic so that the last element case is in the else clause.  This is a general optimization not specific to GPUs so that the more common case falls through rather than having to make a jump.